# A WAR file created from Eclipse does not work from browser, but it works when the war file is expanded

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, war

I created a simple HelloWorld project in Eclipse. It runs within Eclipse fine.
When I created a WAR file, it does not. The WAR file's name is test.war, and the file is placed in webapps\ROOT\temp.

I tested as localhost:8080/temp/test.
The error message is

```
HTTP Status 404 - /temp/test
type Status report
message /temp/test
description The requested resource is not available.
```

I unzipped the war file as "jar -cvf test.war" in the same directory.
The war file contains index.jsp, and when unzipped, it works when I tested as 
 localhost:8080/temp/

Any idea why the index.jsp is not picked up from the war file?

Comment: Hmmmm. You get a 404 not found with /temp/test, but then you call /temp. Don't you have any test/ directory in your war? Shouldn't it work as /test? You do look a bit confused

Comment: The war file does not have any directory. It just has two directories (META-INF and WEB-INF) and index.jsp.

Answer (score -1):

A `WAR` works only when deployed.

Deployment occurs by expanding the archive.

Probably your server does not perform auto-deploy. If it did, you would see files loaded not from the WAR, but from the expanded directory

Comment: I am running on Tomcat 7.0. Isn't auto-deploy set to true by default? How would I check the value?
thx